# LabelFor not displaying value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I'm trying to just display a value in my Razor code. I've tried both DisplayFor and LabelFor. If I use DisplayFor then my value shows up but my CSS doesn't get applied. If I use LabelFor then it's the opposite, my CSS is applied but the text only displays as "EmployeeId". I've confirmed that my ViewModel has a value populated for the EmployeeId prior to going to View.

This is what I've tried:

```
<div class="row voffset2">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        Employee ID: @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmployeeId, new { @class = "control-label label-value" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row voffset2">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        Employee ID: @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.EmployeeId, new { @class = "control-label label-value" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first of all [DisplayFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayfor(v=vs.118).aspx) does not have an overload of `htmlAttributes` so `new { @class = "control-label label-value" }` wont work and secondly [LabelFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions.labelfor(v=vs.118).aspx) does not display value of the property it will just display  the name of the property so
you can do it like this

```
<div class="row voffset2">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        Employee ID: <span class"ontrol-label label-value">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.EmployeeId)</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just FYI: `DisplayFor` is a *templated*-helper. That means, what's output is based on a "display template". The default display template for most property types just outputs the value with no HTML. As a result, there's nothing to apply an `htmlAttributes` param to, even if it actually allowed you to pass that in. You can create your own custom display templates and include HTML, but since it's a custom template, you'd be responsible for setting attributes on your HTML manually. `DisplayFor` accepts `additionalViewData` which you can use to pass in values.

Comment: Thanks, both these answers seem to be correct but it looks like DisplayFor is what I need. I appreciate all the extra info so that I can actually understand the differences between the two helpers.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
public class LabelViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Employee\nId")]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    //display for is for iterating over a collection
    public IList<string> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index54()
    {
        //display for is for iterating over a collection
        LabelViewModel labelViewModel = new LabelViewModel();
        labelViewModel.Employees = new List<string>();
        labelViewModel.Employees.Add("emp1");
        labelViewModel.Employees.Add("emp2");
        return View(labelViewModel);
    }
```

View:

```
@model Testy20161006.Controllers.LabelViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index54</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .cssworks {
            color: red
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row voffset2">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            Employee ID: @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmployeeId, new { @class = "cssworks control-label label-value" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row voffset2">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @*display for is for iterating over a collection*@
            @*changed the next line, since you can't put a class in displayfor*@
            Employee ID: <span class="cssworks">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Employees)</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```